# Android : Not able to find application on SD card

Tags: android

I have installed app in the device but not able to find it on sd card.
I gave /data/data/com.abc.xyz/databases path as the  install path. but it is not showing in sd card.

actually i am unzipping the file in SD card from res/raw folder.

Just want to know where my data has gone? How can I read and write SD card data.

Below is code

```
final InputStream myInput = new GZIPInputStream( this.myContext.getResources( ).openRawResource(
                R.raw.clc_android ) );

        String dir = Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM;

        final String outFileName = DB_PATH+DB_NAME;

        if (new File(DB_PATH).exists() == false) {

            new File(DB_PATH).mkdirs();
        }

        final OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream( outFileName );

        //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
        final byte[ ] buffer = new byte[ 1024 ];
        int length;
        while ( ( length = myInput.read( buffer ) ) > 0 )
        {
            myOutput.write( buffer, 0, length );
        }
```

Below is android manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.clc.encyclopedia" android:versionCode="23"
android:versionName="14.0" android:installLocation="auto">

<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="20" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>   
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" /> 
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Hi where you want to copy the file? The file is database file or normal file. and what you want to do finally.

Comment: I have kept zipped db file in res/raw folder. I want to unzip and copy sqlite database file on SD card.  after unzip file name will be abc.sqlite.  I have given DB_PATH as /data/data/packagename/databses/

Comment: /data/data/packagename/databses/ this is application local  database path, you really want to extract over here. because the path is not related to the sd card It is related to default database location.

Comment: yes i would love to use the same path. Actually this path is not showing in the file manager...so i thought to use SD card. But another problem is later on I want to use new db file. when i keep new db file in raw folder it still uses old db file.

Comment: Only you application has access of this path  /data/data/packagename/databses/, that's why the file manager does not display it.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I can show you how to copy the database over the sd card. I try to modified your posted code see below.

```
private static String EXTERNAL_STORAGE = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();

private static String DIR_APP_HOME = "yourapphome";

private static String getExternalStoragePath() {
        return new StringBuilder().append(EXTERNAL_STORAGE).append("/").toString();
}

public static String appHomeDirectory() {
        return new StringBuilder().append(getExternalStoragePath()).append(DIR_APP_HOME).append("/").toString();
}


public static void verifyAppHomePath() {
        File mFile = new File(appHomeDirectory());
        if (!mFile.exists()) {
            mFile.mkdir();
        }
        mFile = null;
}
```

Now how to use above all function inside your code. This will create the directory inside your sd card with your desire name.

```
final InputStream myInput = new GZIPInputStream( this.myContext.getResources( ).openRawResource(R.raw.clc_android ) );

String dir = Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM;

// this will verify the directory is present or not if not present then it will create the empty directory
verifyAppHomePath();

// assign the your application home directory
DB_PATH = appHomeDirectory();

// build the database path with database file name
final String outFileName = DB_PATH+DB_NAME;

final OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream( outFileName );

//transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile 
final byte[ ] buffer = new byte[ 1024 ];
int length;
while ( ( length = myInput.read( buffer ) ) > 0 )
{ 
    myOutput.write( buffer, 0, length );
}
```

Let me know if you have any question, if you do not know how to access the sd card database let me know. thank you.

Comment: Thanks for the help...but above code is for external SD card, what about internal sd card? if user doesnt have external sd card then where it will store the data?

Comment: In short you can not directly access the local database. I mean through your application programtically you can create and delete but third party application can not.

Comment: I think you just want to copy the database from raw directory to actual application location, that you want to try correct.

Comment: Then do not think about sd card, you have to just focus on the path where your want to copy the data base in your case it would " 
/data/data/packagename/databses/abc.db".

Comment: will i be able to move application to sd card if i have installlocation as auto in manifest file..